# Find the index of all occurrences of 'a' in the string x

Tags: python, enumerate

Programming is all fine but I don't know the meaning of idx for idx.
I know function enumerate(): for idx, c in enumerate
but what is idx for idx meaning??

input

```
x = 'An apple a day, keeps the doctor away'
j = [idx for idx, c in enumerate(x,  start = 0) if c == 'a']
print(j)
```

output
[3, 9, 12, 33, 35]

Comment: How would you write it as a `for` loop? Maybe comparing that with this comprehension will give you an answer

Comment: `idx` is index when you use `enumerate` it iterates the value and the index of the value.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, idx iterates over the indices of the string x while c iterates over its values.

So when `c == 'a'`, idx (which is the index of this 'a') will be added to the list.

Think it more like `idx for (idx, c) in enumerate(x,  start = 0) if c == 'a'`

Answer (score 0):

This is known as list comprehension, I would suggest looking up a few examples of list comprehension.

Here it is enumerating through the string, where `idx` is the index for each character, and `c` is the character itself. `idx for idx, c in ... if c == 'a'` is basically saying append `idx` to this new list if `c == a`. It is a one line way of writing the below:

```
j = []
for idx, c in enumerate(x,  start = 0):
    if c == 'a':
        j.append(idx)
```

Comment: Thaks I got it.

Comment: @LeeeJeff if this helped, it would be good if you could accept and upvote (on the left of the question)